# Google Cloud Run CLI inserting a whitespace in the beginning of my command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I created a docker container with a python script to execute using the Cloud Run Job from GCP. My script runs a code like this:

```
python3.9 extract_parquet.py --table_name users
```

I used the Google Run cli to create my job, running the following command:

```
gcloud run jobs create extract_parquet --region=us-central1 --memory=4Gi --cpu=4 --task-timeout=4h --max-retries=0 --image=us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/hyper-suite/hyper-suite:latest --command="python3.9, extract_parquet.py, --table_name, users"
```

However, when I try to execute this job, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/python3.9: can't open file '/usr/src/app/ extract_parquet.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Note that there is an extra whitespace after /app/ which indicates the problem, although I don't know what this behavior occurs. If I manually edit the command option on Google interface and hit the backspace button, the command runs smoothly.

I also found a possible problem on the yaml configuration as showed below. There is no apostrophe on python command, but I'm not sure if this impact on my problem.

[image]

UPDATE:  manually edit the command option on Google interface the yaml removes the apostrophes from my execution command as shown below:

[image]

Anyone knows why this is happening and how to solve this? Sincerely.

Comment: Does it work with your update?

Comment: Work, yes. But I had to update it manually. The code is supposed to run automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from the command line. Remove the space here

```
Don't do that
--command="python3.9, extract_parquet.py, --table_name, users"

But do this
--command="python3.9,extract_parquet.py,--table_name,users"
```

space after a comma is for human readability. Here, the comma is a arg separator, no human involved!

Answer (score 1):

The Guillaume answer worked fine! However, I'm going to post a different solution for those who want to try something different.

I split the command in two:

```
gcloud run jobs deploy extract-parquet --region=us-central1 --image=us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/hyper-suite/hyper-suite:latest

gcloud run jobs replace config.yaml --region=us-central1
```

This solution deploys a job run with no config at all, then this config is added using the replace command. The configuration is added on a yaml file to be loaded on replace command. The yaml file should look like this:

```
apiVersion: run.googleapis.com/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: extract-parquet
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      taskCount: 1
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - image: us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/hyper-suite/hyper-suite:latest
            command:
            - python3.9
            - extract_parquet.py
            - --table_name
            - users
            resources:
              limits:
                cpu: 4000m
                memory: 4Gi
          maxRetries: 0
          timeoutSeconds: '14400'
          serviceAccountName: your_account_name
```

This solution is particularly useful if you have a command with lots of parameters.